# How to add line to chart

Tags: javascript, charts, c3.js

I'm using C3 js to generate a chart. In my chart, I'm currently using stack bars to showing the data.

My code,

```
<div id="chart"></div>

<script>

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['Blue', 30, 200, 200, 400, 150, 250],
            ['Orange', 130, 100, 100, 200, 150, 50],
            ['Green', 230, 200, 200, 300, 250, 250]
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        groups: [
            ['Blue', 'Orange','Green']
        ]
    }
});

</script>
```

According to the above code, chart generate as,

[image]

Now I need to add an additional 3 line to that chart, as below image,

How can I add Lines to chart using C3 JS? Its [document](https://c3js.org/gettingstarted.html) has some line chart with a bar chart. But I can understand how to use it's for my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.types` to set a chart for each data, Read this: https://c3js.org/reference.html#data-types .And this is a sample code for your problem.

```
<script>

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['Blue', 30, 200, 200, 400, 150, 250],
            ['Orange', 130, 100, 100, 200, 150, 50],
            ['Green', 230, 200, 200, 300, 250, 250],
            ['Black', 150, 160, 140, 145, 250, 100],
            ['Pink', 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50],
            ['Red', 400, 200, 150, 20, 300, 120]
        ],
        types:{
           Blue : 'bar',
           Orange : 'bar',
           Green : 'bar',
           Black : 'line',
           Pink : 'line',
           Red : 'line'
        },
        groups: [
            ['Blue', 'Orange','Green']
        ]
    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can achieve it instead of `type` use `types`

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
 bindto: '#chart',
 data: {
  columns: [
   ['Blue', 30, 200, 200, 400, 150, 250],
    ['Orange', 130, 100, 100, 200, 150, 50],
   ['Green', 230, 200, 200, 300, 250, 250],
      ['Black', 30, 200, 200, 400, 150, 250],
      ['Pink', 130, 100, 100, 200, 150, 50],
   ['Red', 230, 200, 200, 300, 250, 250]
  ],
  types: {
    Blue : 'bar',
       Orange : 'bar',
       Green : 'bar',
       Black : 'line',
       Pink : 'line',
       Red : 'line'
  },
  groups: [
   ['Blue','Orange', 'Green', 'Black','Pink', 'Red']
  ],      
  axes: {
   Black: 'black',
   Pink: 'pink',
   Red: 'red',

   }
 },
 color: {
  pattern: ['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c','#00000', '#ff69b4', '#ff0000']},
 axis: {
  black: {
   show: true 
  },pink: {
   show: true 
  },red: {
   show: true 
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<!-- Load c3.css -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.2/c3.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.7/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.2/c3.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```